# If I don't desire single clicks to wrongly turn into double clicks, do I increase or decrease Double-click speed?

Tags: windows, mouse

1. My grandma got a new Lenovo mouse, but to her chagrin, it's treating her single clicks as double clicks. She read [this](https://www.solveyourtech.com/how-to-change-your-double-click-mouse-speed-in-windows-10/).
2. How do we interpret the folder test? When she dragged Speed all the right to "Fast" and single-clicked on the Folder, the Folder opened. When she dragged Speed all the left to "Slow", the Folder didn't close. She had to click many times repeatedly for the folder to close.

[image]

Comment: Decreasing the speed would help and increasing would help as well, depends on how the input is, if she clicks slowly and it is interpreted as a double click then increase the speed and if she clicks fast and it is interpreted as a double click then decrease the speed. Try the folder test on the right side to see which one suits better.

Comment: @Valay_17 Thanks. Does my edit affect your answer?

Comment: 1) Ok so it should be near the slow setting to prevent double clicks. 2) Try adjusting the slider to a place(mostly towards slow) where she can both be able to double click and single click easily. Hope you understand what I mean by the second point.

Comment: You can turn explorer and desktop into a internet mode where only single clicks work. In Explorer View ribbon, Options, Change Folder and Search Options, Single Click To Open Items (Point To Select).

Comment: @Mark It is not what the OP desires.